# Getting a list of results, 1 for each foreign key

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have a model, `Reading`, which has a foreign key, `Type`. I'm trying to get a reading for each type that I have, using the following code:

```
    for type in Type.objects.all():
        readings = Reading.objects.filter(
                type=type.pk)
        if readings.exists():
            reading_list.append(readings[0])
```

The problem with this, of course, is that it hits the database for each sensor reading. I've played around with some queries to try to optimize this to a single database call, but none of them seem efficient. `.values` for instance will provide me a list of readings grouped by type, but it will give me EVERY reading for each type, and I have to filter them with Python in memory. This is out of the question, as we're dealing with potentially millions of readings.

Answer (score 0):

if you use PostgreSQL as your DB backend you can do this in one-line with something like:

```
Reading.objects.order_by('type__pk', 'any_other_order_field').distinct('type__pk')
```

Note that the field on which distinct happens must always be the first argument in the `order_by` method. Feel free to change `type__pk` with the actuall field you want to order types on (e.g. `type__name` if the `Type` model has a `name` property). You can read more about distinct here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct.

If you do not use PostgreSQL you could use the `prefetch_related` method for this purpose:

```
#reading_set could be replaced with whatever your reverse relation name actually is
for type in Type.objects.prefetch_related('reading_set').all():
        readings = type.reading_set.all()
        if len(readings):
            reading_list.append(readings[0])
```

The above will perform only 2 queries in total. Note I use len() so that no extra query is performed when counting the objects. You can read more about `prefetch_related` here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related.

On the downside of this approach is you first retrieve all related objects from the DB and then just get the first.

The above code is not tested, but I hope it will at least point you towards the right direction.

Comment: The above code looks like it performs two queries per Type, which is actually no better than my current code. Probably a bit worse, since it prefetches every reading into memory, and we are talking about potentially millions of readings here.

Comment: Hello, are you sure you're getting two queries per type? I just tried the prefetch version and it's just two queries in total as it should. As far as memory goes, agreed, this solution should not be used for lots of data. As I say in the answer this snippet fetches all related objects from the DB, so it actually depends on the data set.